# LINQ alternative

Tags: c#, linq, foreach

I have a dictionary which I am going to convert into query string.

```
var encryptionItems = new Dictionary<string,string>();
encryptionItems.Add("customerid", row.CustomerId.ToString());
encryptionItems.Add("firstname",model.FirstName); 
encryptionItems.Add("lastname",model.LastName);

var get = encryptionDal.EncryptDataWithSalt(encryptionItems, salt);
var linkUri = string.Empty;
foreach (var item in get)
{
    linkUri = string.Concat(linkUri, item.Key, "=", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(item.Value), "&");
}
```

I want write the foreach loop in LINQ format to optimize the code.
Dont know how to do it. can anyone suggest me something ?

Comment: Does LINQ actually _"optimize the code"_?

Comment: To be honest I would leave it as is. LINQ will not actually be any more performant and in some cases I find the syntax is obscures the intention of the code making it harder to maintain.

Comment: @MickyD - No, LINQ does not "optimize" code in terms of performance. But it might "optimize" code in terms of readability. That's highly debatable though. Especially if the developer themself (or members of the team) are not used to LINQ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need an explicit loop.  `String.Join()` was made to do this.

```
var encrypted = encryptionDal.EncryptDataWithSalt(encryptionItems, salt); // assuming it returns a Dictionary<string, string>
var queryString = String.Join("&",
    from kvp in encrypted
    select $"{WebUtility.UrlEncode(kvp.Key)}={WebUtility.UrlEncode(kvp.Value)}"
);
```

On the other hand, you might not want the overhead of using LINQ.  If you're going to use a loop, use a `StringBuilder` when you have a potentially unknown number of strings to add.

```
var encrypted = encryptionDal.EncryptDataWithSalt(encryptionItems, salt);
var sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var kvp in encrypted)
    sb.AppendFormat("&{0}={1}", WebUtility.UrlEncode(kvp.Key), WebUtility.UrlEncode(kvp.Value));
var queryString = sb.ToString(1, sb.Length-1); // assuming non-empty
```

Answer (score 1):

To be honest I would leave it as is. LINQ will not actually be any more performant and in some cases I find the syntax obscures the intention of the code, making it harder to maintain.

That said though, the shortest answer I can provide however is:

```
  var encryptionItems = new Dictionary<string, string>
  {
    {"customerid", row.CustomerId.ToString()},
    {"firstname", model.FirstName},
    {"lastname", model.LastName}
  };

  var get = encryptionDal.EncryptDataWithSalt(encryptionItems, salt);
  var linkUri = get.Aggregate(string.Empty, (current, item) => string.Concat(current, item.Key, "=", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(item.Value), "&"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var linkUri = get.Aggregate(string.Empty,
                    (current, item) => string.Concat(current, item.Key, "=", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(item.Value), "&"));
```